# Can someone help in Bulkifying the below Apex code. The purpose here is to Remove Product Sharing When user is removed from AccountTeamMember

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

The purpose here is to Remove Product Sharing When user is removed from AccountTeamMember.

```
 List<AccountTeamMember> acctmListProd = [Select id,UserId, AccountId, TeamMemberRole FROM 
                                            AccountTeamMember WHERE Id In:acctmList and 
                                            TeamMemberRole IN:Roles]
    
    Map<Id,Id> accToUserIdList = new Map<Id,Id>();
    for(AccountTeamMember At: acctmListProd)
    {
     accToUserIdList.put(At.AccountId, At.UserId);
    
    }
    List<Product__Share> DelProdShareRecords = new List<Product__Share>();
    Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>();
    
    for(Id accId: accToUserIdList.keySet())
    {
       List<Product__c> prodList = [Select id,Account__c from Product__c where 
                                    Account__c=accId];
    
       for(Product__c prod: prodList)
       {
         productIds.add(prod.Id);
       }
       List<Product__Share> prodShareRecords = [Select id,ParentId,UserOrGroupId from 
                                               Product__Share where ParentId IN:productIds AND 
                                               UserOrGroupId=accToUserList.get(accId)
                                               ];
       DelProdShareRecords.addAll(prodShareRecords);
    }
    if(!DelProdShareRecords.isEmpty())
    {
     Database.deleteResult[] result = Database.delete(DelProdShareRecords, false);
    }
```

Comment: This is not compilable Apex. There are multiple syntax errors, particularly around Apex variable binds. Regardless, the bulkification pattern you need is already in this code, you've simply failed to use it on one query.

Answer (score 0):

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgUVUAZ/allow-global-security-and-sharing-rules-settings-on-products

Product__Share isn't a thing. This code looks like it was never compiled or tested in an org.